# Can i containerise console app with vs2019 into ACR, seems only dotnetcore web apps will work

Tags: docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, azure-container-registry

I am using VS2019 with docker support (and windows docker running). When creating a console app there is no checkbox for docker support like there is for a dotnetcore web app. This means i cannot publish a container to ACR from VS2019.

I can create a console app and then add docker support and i can build image but embarrassing enough i cannot locate the image that's built or figure how to get it into ACR. running docker ps -a shows nothing in the container list.

So: is there support for pushing containers to ACR from VS2019 console apps?

If not then exactly how do i build a docker image of a console app and get it to ACR - am i left with CLI only?

thanks
Paul

Comment: How do you create the Docker image in the VS2019 console apps? In the PowerShell script?

Comment: Create a new console app, right click Add Docker support which gives you the docker file. Then right click on that and Build Image - it goes through the process but i cannot find the resulting image. The paths described in the build process don't exist (they are relative though)

Comment: I see the steps about [Running console applications in Windows container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/docker/console) through the PowerShell script. So it seems you can add the push command in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.

The issue was that the underlying version of windows 10 i was on would not allow me to create a docker image using a more modern supported version of windows nano server. Once i updated windows and double checked the base image that create image was using it would all work. Take the resulting docker image and use the azure cli to push to ACR and then i can run the container from ACI...

Bit tortuous compared to creating a web app but it worked...